# Hawthorn identification

Tags: identification, trees, flowers, leaves

I have a question on the identification of two trees, which I am pretty sure are hawthorn species. First of all, where I live: Gants Hill, London, England, UK. I took the two photos below in the middle of last month, i.e. mid-May.

[image]
[image]

I’m very sure the top one is Common Hawthorn (*Crataegus monogyna*) but not so sure about the bottom one. I think it may be Midland Hawthorn (*Crataegus laevigata*). The leaves are clearly different: those of the *C. monogyna* (top) have lobes with deep cuts while those of tree below have shallower lobes – characteristics which are consistent with what I’ve gathered from my own Google research on the two species.

So, does anyone know if the bottom one is *C. laevigata*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly looks like C. laevigata, possibly the variety 'Paul's Scarlet', though that usually has double flowers, so perhaps 'Crimson Cloud' but C. laevigata either way - the coloration does differ somewhat between individual trees, and over time. Link below showing C. 'crimson cloud'

https://www.greenplantswap.co.uk/plants/5389-crataegus-laevigata-crimson-cloud

Most images show Crimson Cloud as quite red, but in real life, they may start out quite red but turn more pink, or be more pink than red in the first place.

Comment: Yes, I did wonder if it might be Paul’s Scarlet but was doubtful on account of the pale central part of the flowers.

Comment: Your link needs updating, just displays "Page Not Found (Error 404)" @bamboo

Answer (score 1):

It can't be 'Paul's Scarlet'. It is 'Punicea', 'Crimson Cloud' or 'Superba'.

From [Horticulture Week](https://www.google.rs/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.hortweek.com/crataegus/landscape/article/806871&ved=0ahUKEwjO0L2H1rLXAhUjB8AKHVM9DIsQFggwMAE&usg=AOvVaw1OziEZtfofxGB-Fec5JydA):

> C. laevigata 'Crimson Cloud' has red single flowers that appear in mid-spring with a pronounced white centre. It has a moderate rate of growth and prefers damp sites with a sunny aspect. It reaches 4m, sometimes with a slightly weeping habit.

You can find descriptions and photos of other mentioned cultivars on the net and compare them to your tree.